# How do you create a JSON object within a JSON array using Ruby's json_builder?

Tags: ruby, json

How do I use Ruby's [json_builder](https://github.com/dewski/json_builder#readme) to create a JSON object within a JSON array?  For example, how do I create the following structure?

```
{
  Object: [
    "x",
    { 
      "Foo" : "Bar" 
    },
    "y"
  ]
}
```

Note: these types of structures are used in AWS's Cloud Formation API

Comment: Perhaps the answer is "don't use json_builder" :(

Comment: Are there any similar ruby JSON templating DSLs that can do this cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [`JBuilder`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) over `json_builder`. It is targeted at Rails applications, but its a Ruby gem and can be used otherwise.

The github page also has links to other json builder gems.

Comment: Any particular reason you recommend JBuilder over json_builder? As the author of json_builder, I spent a lot of time on the API of the library and would like to think it's the simplest JSON generating library out there without sacrificing features or speed.

Comment: Actually, I should have mentioned it here, I only recommended it because it was made a Rails default.

Comment: Also, the API being similar to the XML builder API is a minor, but added advantage of JBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the example code needed to generate a JSON object as shown in the question.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json_builder'

json = JSONBuilder::Compiler.generate(:pretty => true) do
 Object ['x', { :Foo => 'Bar' }, 'y']
end

puts json
```

As the author of json_builder, let me know if you need any other help, but the README is fairly straightforward and could always use improvement if you have a hard time finding example usage.

Answer (score 0):

Interestly, "regular" `require 'json'` works well as a DSL:

```
require 'json'

json = {
  :Object => [
    "x",
    {
      :Foo => "Bar"
    },
    "y"
  ]
}

puts JSON.pretty_generate(json)
```